# Javascript - How to unmute youtube videos in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, youtube-api

My youtube videos perfectly in iframe but there is no sound. Below is my code.

```
if (slideType === "youtube") {
    switch (control) {
      case "play":
        postMessageToPlayer(player, {
          "event": "command",
          "func": "mute"
        });
        postMessageToPlayer(player, {
          "event": "command",
          "func": "playVideo" 
        });
        break;
      case "pause":
        postMessageToPlayer(player, {
          "event": "command",
          "func": "pauseVideo"
        });
        break;
    }
  }

// POST commands to YouTube API
function postMessageToPlayer(player, command){
  if (player == null || command == null) return;
  player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");
}
```

From the above section if i remove the mute section the video does not play. If i send unMute instead of mute still the video does not play. How do i have sound for my video being played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until and unless you have `allow="autoplay;"` in your `iframe` tag you wont be able to `unmute` the video. Add this attribute and further `unMute` function will work.

Answer (score -2):

Usually, you can just click the mute button to unmute it.

Comment: There is no mute button

Comment: Could you add a picture?